# two images and text overlaping

Tags: html, css

I want to get the same output you can see, for example on [genius.com](http://genius.com).

There is:

> (1) big image
>
> (2) small squares over that image
>
> (3) text (links) plus some small images over (1) and (2)

The difference in what I want to do is that the (1) images are uploaded by users, not posted as static content (e.g. posted as background image, like on genius.com).

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img alt="" class="bg-img" src="http://xyz3etr4qqrrx.cloudfront.net/uploads/picture/image/2/image.png" />
  <div class="text-plus-links">Text...</div>
</div>
```

css (an attempt)

```
.bg-img{width:300px; height:250px;}
.text-plus-links{display:table; margin-top:-250px;...}

/* small image that adds the squares */
opacity: 0.2;
background: asset-url("http://genius.com/images/tooth_bg.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

Comment: this is not a question this is a home work (I want to do is that the images is uploaded by users, not posted as static content) are you serious ?

Comment: What home work?? I'm saying that the (1) image is not a background image and posted there manually.

Answer (score 1):

First things first if the pictures are going to be uploaded by the users that means you will need a server-side script and potentially somewhere to store the images. You can not store data on the client side since the code is renewed on everypage load (exceptions browser cookies).

**Solution1**

Here is a static solution to what you are looking.

https://jsfiddle.net/jd6c7fdj/2/

Just change the background-color to background image and set the transparency

However since the the images will be loaded by the user, you have to detect image properties and set everything accordingly

**Solution 2**

A more elegant solution would be keeping the divs of a static width and height and setting images as their background images

The downside of this is the size of the image will be highly restricted but it will save you a lot of code

Again this is much more elegant

https://jsfiddle.net/e1pktges/1/

```
<div class="whatever">
   <div class="cover">
      <p> Hello </p>
      <p> yess </p>
    </div>
</div>


 .cover{
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: 500;
   position: absolute;
   width: 700px;
   height: 500px;
 }

p{
  color: white;
}

.whatever{
  background-image: url("http://www.lucamartincigh.com/wp-      content/uploads/2010/11/fullscreen-website-template.png");
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
} 
}
```